# Sorting dataframe cells based on extracted value?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '0 0 1 apple' | '0 0 2 banana' | '7 5 6 orange' | '4 2 9 mango' |
| '2 8 0 grape' | '3 7 5 apple' | '7 4 1 banana' | '0 5 3 kiwi' |
| '3 8 4 lemon' | '5 0 7 grape' | '3 8 9 pineapple' | '6 1 8 watermelon' |
| '3 7 6 orange' | '0 1 8 lemon' | '1 6 7 cherry' | '2 9 0 raspberry' |
| '5 2 7 cherry' | '2 9 7 pear' | 'NaN' | 'NaN' |

Each cell contains a string value of the following type: `'x y z SomeText'`. I want to reorder the columns from 'Column_2' onwards based on the 'z' value within the same row. The 'Column_1' should remain unchanged. THe output should look like:

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '0 0 1 apple' | '4 2 **9** mango' | '7 5 **6** orange' | '0 0 **2** banana' |
| '2 8 9 grape' | '3 7 **5** apple' | '0 5 **3** kiwi' | '7 4 **1** banana' |
| '3 8 4 lemon' | '3 8 **9** pineapple' | '6 1 **8** watermelon' | 'grape 5 0 **7**' |

etc.

The real data frame looks like this:

[image]

I would like the file to be read so that the final result would have, e.g., the following values swapped:

[image]

As you can see, `6 0 6 zwOl@` and `3 0 3 swOl@` should be re-ordered based on the third digit in each string.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe as code (`df.head().to_dict()`) and not as an image.

Comment: What is the criteria for sorting? Which rows in your example would need to be sorted? Can you provide your expected output and/or a sample of your input file?

Comment: @not_speshal I have added a toy example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want every row sorted in ascending order of the 3rd number except for `Column_1`. If so, try:

```
output = (df.iloc[:,0].to_frame()
          .join(df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda row: row.sort_values(key=lambda x: x.str.split().str[2],
                                                                ascending=False,
                                                                ignore_index=True),
                                    axis=1))
          )

>>> output
       Column_1         Column_2          Column_3         Column_4
0   0 0 1 apple      4 2 9 mango      7 5 6 orange     0 0 2 banana
1   2 8 0 grape      3 7 5 apple        0 5 3 kiwi     7 4 1 banana
2   3 8 4 lemon  3 8 9 pineapple  6 1 8 watermelon      5 0 7 grape
3  3 7 6 orange      0 1 8 lemon      1 6 7 cherry  2 9 0 raspberry
4  5 2 7 cherry       2 9 7 pear               NaN              NaN
```

Comment: This does not quite work: it completely changes the structure of Column_1

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dataframe with the columns that have to be sorted, then sort it and join back with Column_1:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# set seed
random.seed(42)
# Create a DataFrame
data = []
for _ in range(5):  # 5 rows
    x = random.randint(0, 10)
    y = random.randint(0, 10)
    z = random.randint(0, 10)
    text = f'{x} {y} {z} SomeText'
    data.append(text.split())

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column_1', 'Column_2', 'Column_3', 'Column_4'])

print(f"df before sorting:\n{df}")

df before sorting:
  Column_1 Column_2 Column_3  Column_4
0       10        1        0  SomeText
1        4        3        3  SomeText
2        2        1       10  SomeText
3        8        1        9  SomeText
4        6        0        0  SomeText

df_to_order = df[["Column_2", "Column_3", "Column_4"]]

df = df_to_order.\
    sort_values(by=["Column_2", "Column_3", "Column_4"]).\
    join(df[["Column_1"]])[[
        "Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_3", "Column_4"
    ]]

print(f"df after sorting:\n{df}")

df after sorting:
  Column_1 Column_2 Column_3  Column_4
4        6        0        0  SomeText
0       10        1        0  SomeText
2        2        1       10  SomeText
3        8        1        9  SomeText
1        4        3        3  SomeText
```

Comment: Sorry, I have mistyped the toy examples: the digits are all in the same cell together with the text. See my edit!